# Defining a function as a compound proposition

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The problem I am trying to solve is asking me to define a function as a compound proposition. For example *f(p,q)* as $\lnot$*p$\to$q*. The question I am trying to define ass a compound proposition is *f* is both injective and surjective. I came up with the answer *p$\to$q*. My reasoning for this is that the function is one-to-one because no two elements in the domain are assigned to the same codomain. Also the function is surjective because all elements of the codomain is an image of the element in the domain. I'm looking for some clarification to see if I answered the problem correctly, or if I'm completely wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

**Sorry if my post isn't up to par.This is my first post on this website.**

Comment: How can $f$ be bijective if its domain and codomain are not equal?